# Highlighting links not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, highlight

I have a navbar set up with some  links. The whole link area should highlight gray, and it used to work. Then I decided to build my navbar in a better way and re-write it, but `a:hover` isn't working anymore.

**Same Code:**

```css
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:link {
    color:green;
}
a:visited {
    color:white
}
.idfour, 
.idfive a:hover {
    background-color:#A8B1A9 !important;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="total">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div style="overflow: auto">
                    <div class="idtwo" style="width:15%;display:block;border-left: 1px solid    white;padding:0;font-size:12px;float:right;margin-right:0px">
                        <a href="logoff.php" style="border-right:none"><p style="margin-top:15px"><b>Logout</b></p></a>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="idthree" style="width:20%;display:block;border-right:1px solid white;border-left: 1px solid white;padding:0;font-size:12px;float:right">
                        <a href="myaccount.php"><p style="margin-top:15px"><b>My account</b></p></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="idfour" style="width:20%;display:block;border-right:1px solid white;border-left: 1px solid white;padding:0;font-size:12px;float:right">
                        <a href="myprofile.php"><p style="margin-top:8px"><b>My Profile</b></p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </div>  
</nav>
```

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: Where is **idfive**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6ehkLm4e/)**

Add class `.hoverlink` (or whatever you want to name it) along with idtwo, idthree, idfour

so your html will look like this

```
<nav>
<div class="total">
<ul>
<li>
<div style="overflow: auto">
<div class="idtwo hoverlink" style="width:15%;display:block;border-left: 1px solid    white;padding:0;font-size:12px;float:right;margin-right:0px">
<a href="logoff.php" style="border-right:none"><p style="margin-top:15px"><b>Logout</b></p></a>
</div> 
<div class="idthree hoverlink" style="width:20%;display:block;border-right:1px solid white;border-left: 1px solid white;padding:0;font-size:12px;float:right">
 <a href="myaccount.php"><p style="margin-top:15px"><b>My account</b></p></a>
</div>
<div class="idfour hoverlink" style="width:20%;display:block;border-right:1px solid white;border-left: 1px solid white;padding:0;font-size:12px;float:right">
<a href="myprofile.php"><p style="margin-top:8px"><b>My Profile</b></p></a>
</div>
</div>
</li>   
</ul>
<div class="total">  
</nav>
```

and then write this css

```
.hoverlink:hover {
background-color:#A8B1A9 !important;
color: white;
}
```

Solution is very simple, add `:hover` directly to the class.

IMO you should read how `:hover` works. **[This](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/h/hover/)** will help you out